# How to format the DHTMLX Chart and bind value to Pie Chart?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dhtmlx

Am trying to format a simple DHTMLX stacked Horizontal bar chart; Then bind the value to one of the Pie slices in an associated Pie chart, along with binding it to an MVC textbox in an Edit form.

Problem 1: the Horizontal bar chart has 3 labels shown: 0, 50, 100.  Not what I wanted, but its ok, what's not ok is the format.  The 0 is set so that its halfway on the bar chart, the 50 is centered and ok, the 100 is also halfway over the right end of the chart.  Every and any setting I can find, for days, I have modified and NOTHING alters this.

Where it should be:  0 [ ...chart data..  50  ... chart data..   ]  100
its showing up as   ([) ....data... 50 ... data... 10])   with the Left 0 sitting on the center of the chart border, same for the 100 on the right border.

The MVC variable is @Model.PercentData1 and whatever its set to should reflect in both the bar chart and the respective slice in the Pie chart.   Each section will have a Pie chart and each @Model.PercentData2, 3, 4... will operate on their own Pie slice.  I had the barchart value linked or bound to an html textbox and had it working with @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.PercentData1)  whereas EditorFor would do nothing.

The goal initially is to find where the 0, 50 and 100 are coming from and why they are set where they are.  They should be spaced apart from the chart itself and the 100 should be "100 %"

The code with the Pie chart and Bar chart, some parts are commented out, there will be 10 Pie charts, one per group, which operates on a different, unique Pie slice

```
  var pieChart = new dhtmlXChart({
                    view: "pie3D",
                    container: "chart_container",
                    value: "#sales#",
                    //  gradient:true,
                    color: "#color#",
                    cant:0.6,
                    //gradient: function (gradient) {
                    //    gradient.addColorStop(0.0, "#FF0000");
                    //    gradient.addColorStop(0.8, "#FFFF00");
                    //    gradient.addColorStop(1.0, "#00FF22");
                    //},
                    label:"#year#",
                    //legend: {
                    //    width: 45,
                    //    align: "right",
                    //    valign: "top",
                    //    marker: {
                    //        type: "square",
                    //        width: 12
                    //    },
                    //    template: "#year#"
                    //}

                })


                var data = [
    { sales: "4.3", year: "Group 1", color: "#80ff7a" },
    { sales: "9.9", year: "Group 2", color: "#bdff33" },
    { sales: "7.4", year: "Group 3", color: "#ff9e2a" },
    { sales: "9.0", year: "Group 4", color: "#ff561b" },
    { sales: "7.3", year: "Group 5", color: "#ff71be" },
    { sales: "6.8", year: "Group 6", color: "#ffea69" },
    { sales: "7.4", year: "Group 7", color: "#ff9e2a" },
    { sales: "9.0", year: "Group 8", color: "#ff561b" },
    { sales: "7.3", year: "Group 9", color: "#ff71be" },
    { sales: "6.8", year: "Group 10", color: "#ffea69" }
                ];
                pieChart.parse(data, "json");



                amtUsed = 25;
                myBarChart = new dhtmlXChart({
                    view: "stackedBarH",
                    container: "chartDiv",
                    value: "#spent#",
                    color: "#1b66da",
                    width: 50,
                    border:false,
                    alpha: 0.7,

                    //legend: {
                    //    width: 25,
                    //    align: "right",
                    //    valign: top,
                    //    marker: {
                    //        type: "round",
                    //        width: 15
                    //    },
                    //    values: [
                    //    { text: "company A", color: "#3399ff" },
                    //    { text: "company B", color: "#66cc00", markerType: "item" }
                    //    ]
                    //},

                    xAxis: {
                        start: 0,

                        end: 120
                    },
                    //padding: {
                    //    left: 30,
                    //    right:30
                    //},
                    yAxis: {
                        template: "   "
                    }
                });
                myBarChart.addSeries({
                    value: function (obj) {
                        return 100 - obj.spent;
                    },
                    color: "#eaeaea",
                    label: "",
                    tooltip:{template:"   "}
                });
                my_data = [{ spent: amtUsed }];
                myBarChart.parse(my_data, "json");
```

Answer (score 0):

xAxis configuration should contain "start", "end" and "step" properties. In the other case, the scale will be calculated.

And if you want to change the position of "0" and "120" labels, you can apply css styling in the "template" method:

```
xAxis:{
    start:0,
    step:20,
    end:120,
    template:function(value){
        if(value==0)
            value = "<div style='margin-left:5px'>"+value+"</div>";
        else if(value==120)
            value = "<div style='margin-right:15px'>"+value+"</div>";
        return value;
    }
}
```